# The relationship between attributive adjective postposition(관형격 조사)'ㅅ' in medival Korean language and 사이시옷 in modern Korean language

Tags: grammar, history-of-korean, adjective-endings

Though it is just a guess, is there any historical relationship between attributive adjective postposition(`관형격 조사`)'ㅅ' in medival Korean language and `사이시옷` in modern Korean language?

Attributive adjective postposition(`관형격 조사`)'ㅅ' in medival Korean language was used like '의' in modern korean language.

Any materials are appreciated.

Comment: Any extra explanations about the link below are appreciated either!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar question and answer here: (Korean)

https://www.korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do;front=A7F7DEC9E04D4C858034775C804608B9?mn_id=&qna_seq=23137&pageIndex=11509

It says that **Though it differs by scholars, ㅅ in medival Korean had two usage: 관형격 조사(冠形格 助詞, adnominal case postposition) and 사이시옷.**

Hope it helps others who are interested in medival Korean.

Comment: 관형격 冠形格 adnominal case
조사 助詞 postposition